# How to form a icon path that has 'Fill' option in angular echarts?

Tags: javascript, angular, echarts

Here is the link to what I am looking at :

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#toolbox.feature.dataZoom.icon.zoom

While trying to add custom icon to zoom function, wonder how to add 'Fill' option in the path?

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M8.67188 3.14062C7.94531 2.46094 6.98438 2.0625 5.97656 2.0625C4.17188 2.08594 2.60156 3.32812 2.17969 5.03906C2.13281 5.17969 2.01562 5.25 1.89844 5.25H0.5625C0.375 5.25 0.234375 5.10938 0.28125 4.92188C0.773438 2.22656 3.14062 0.1875 6 0.1875C7.54688 0.1875 8.95312 0.820312 10.0078 1.80469L10.8516 0.960938C11.2031 0.609375 11.8125 0.867188 11.8125 1.35938V4.5C11.8125 4.82812 11.5547 5.0625 11.25 5.0625H8.08594C7.59375 5.0625 7.33594 4.47656 7.6875 4.125L8.67188 3.14062ZM0.75 6.9375H3.89062C4.38281 6.9375 4.64062 7.54688 4.28906 7.89844L3.30469 8.88281C4.03125 9.5625 4.99219 9.96094 6 9.96094C7.80469 9.9375 9.375 8.69531 9.79688 6.98438C9.84375 6.84375 9.96094 6.77344 10.0781 6.77344H11.4141C11.6016 6.77344 11.7422 6.91406 11.6953 7.10156C11.2031 9.79688 8.83594 11.8125 6 11.8125C4.42969 11.8125 3.02344 11.2031 1.96875 10.2188L1.125 11.0625C0.773438 11.4141 0.1875 11.1562 0.1875 10.6641V7.5C0.1875 7.19531 0.421875 6.9375 0.75 6.9375Z" fill="#C9CFD4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the color in the path but via the [`iconStyle`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#toolbox.iconStyle) property.

```js
dataZoom: {
    iconStyle: {
        color: 'grey',        // corresponds to the fill color
        borderColor: 'red',   // corresponds to the line color
    }
}
```

Here is a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6AE2aMiAbVoBZGL1i0AKgFcqM2gHUqAlXIAWClQDEOEFQGVmphdFoBdEgF8-6MMGAAbAEbAMRVKVgAzKmYFDhpiP0FhAC0XAFsffgiIehgTClcw3wi_FNdOOlZQ7kds0k8OASoOAGE3fNlQzRLsu0T0Vr8O2AcSchx8BL8KajoAN0ZXJVp7ErwqiCpCWFFErL8hMBFlgEYAVgAGHlgAJgBmQ5PjgBYj4-2ADiPt092nq4B2W4A2fetm0mGYVorgg0GUiS6tjsAG4gA).